# Display JSON data from url using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

We want to display all the names from our json file into a div using javascript. We tried a lot of things, but we didn't manage to succeed.

json data : http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json

This is what we tried :

```
<button>get data</button>
<div id="resultJson"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             $("button").click(function(){
                    $.getJSON("http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json", function(result){
                        for(var x = 0; x < result.length; x++){

                                $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                                    $("#resultJson").append(field[x].name);
                                }

                        }
                    });
            });
```

If anyone can help us with this ploblem, that would be great

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please add any available output written to the screen / log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use extra loop inside for loop to extract name.

Your data is like

```
[0] = {name:"name1"}
[1] = { name: "name2"}
```

If there is a array inside [0] and you want to extract value from that then you need another loop inside for loop to extract that value like you wanna to pull value of `bushaltes`.

Try like this

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json", function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
            $("#resultJson").append(result[x].name);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>get data</button>
<div id="resultJson"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping us so quickly. It works now

Answer (score 1):

you need **either** the `for` loop **or** `$.each` but not both.

Here's the updated code.

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                $("#resultJson").append(field.name);
            });
        });
   });
```

and here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CL55on1eY2kAfD31zgQb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are using jQuery `each` inside your `for` loop.

Additionnaly, I think you should use `result[x].name` instead of `field[x].name` as you are giving `result` as parameter of callback function:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json", function(result){
                        for(var x = 0; x < result.length; x++){
                                    $("#resultJson").append(result[x].name);
                        }
                    });
```

I hope it helps